# How long would a journey to Tau Ceti take from the passengers' perspective at 1/4 the speed of light?

Tags: space-travel, relativity

I'm trying to create a setting where the passengers are in stasis for at least 40 years, possibly longer.

Comment: How long does it take the ship to accelerate?  1 gravity * 3 months is about 1/4 c.  How close does the ship need to be to a star to achieve this acceleration?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems better suited for physics.SE

Comment: @J_F_B_M This still seems like it applies to worldbuilding, the OP may want to ask it on Physics but I don't think that's enough cause to close it here

Comment: I honestly think questions like this don't belong on WorldBuilding. I had a Meta post on it outlining my reasons - basically it boils down to "How long to get from Point A to Point B?" You know the speed of light. You know the distance. It's a mathematical equation. You can put imaginative worlds/obstacles in the way but just take that obstacle and add time to your answer. Other people disagreed, but I have not been given sufficient evidence that "It involves other worlds" gives it an edge over "How long would it take to get to the grocery store from my house?" which is functionally identical.

Comment: @J_F_B_M Voting to reopen, citing "A setting might not be a planet" and "Effects of events or world elements, including biology, technology and magic, on specific aspects of that world's societies, cultures, and environment" and the OP's statement "[...]create a setting where the passengers are[...]"

Comment: I'm having difficulty with the phrasing of the question. It initially sounded like it should be a straight math problem, which would make a migration optimal. But reading it a few times... it almost sounds like they're asking HOW they can make the trip last that long, although if they're unconscious I'm unsure what the point would be. If they're asking what kind of effects or events can happen during the trip that will result in a 40 year stasis, then that would be worldbuilding... right? I would vote to leave it closed as unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha says it takes 416560 hours.  (neglecting relativistic effects)

According to @user6511's query the time dilation is 1.033, so the passengers experience a 46 year trip (from their point of view).

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=distance+to+tau+ceti+from+earth

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=how+long+would+it+take+to+travel+11.88ly+at+1%2F4+the+speed+of+light%3F

Comment: That works out to about 47.5 years.

Comment: It actually says _neglecting relativistic effects_ underneath the Wolfram answer.

Comment: Time dialation at 0.25c is small, but measurable. It's about 3.3%. In effect, it's a smidge over 49 years. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=time+dialation+at+0.25c

Comment: @user6511 Mmm, wouldn't it shorten the time for the passengers rather than lengthen it?

Comment: @user6511 It says "time seen by _stationary_ observer" is 1.033s in a time frame of 1s, but what about the passengers?  I'm not sure how that works exactly.

Comment: Thanks @Jasper for correcting the issue with "time dilation".

Comment: The stationary observer sees the journey taking as long as it takes without relativistic effects. The traveler enjoys the benefit of that approx. 1.5 year difference in time; his journey is that much shorter. In general, relativistic effects are not very significant until your speed is about 2/3 lightspeed.

Comment: In general, if v/c is the traveler's fraction of light speed as seen relative to some inertial observer watching the traveler (like one at rest relative to the Sun), then if a journey takes time T as seen by that inertial observer, the traveler will experience a shorter time of T times the square root of (1 - (v/c)^2), so in this case 47.5*sqrt(1 - 0.25^2) = 46 years.

Comment: Oops. It's been several years since I last studied relativity. It appears I had it backwards. Sorry!

Answer (score 6):

This gets the same result as [Nolo's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/39100/627), but I thought it was worth explicitly going over the relevant math.

We can do the calculation here using the idea of time dilation due to [Lorentz contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor).

The Lorentz factor is
$$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}$$
where $\beta=v/c$. In this case, $v=\frac{1}{4}c$, so $\beta=\frac{1}{4}$ and
$$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}}\approx1.033$$
The distance to [Tau Ceti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tau_Ceti) is about 12 light-years, so in a stationary reference frame, it would take them about 48 years to get there.

However, Lorentz contraction states that
$$d\tau=\gamma^{-1}dt$$
where $\tau$ is the travelers' proper time. Therefore,
$$\tau=\gamma^{-1}t=\frac{1}{1.033}\cdot48=46.48\text{ years}$$

This assumes, of course, a constant $v$. As [Jasper said](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39098/how-long-would-a-journey-to-tau-ceti-take-from-the-passengers-perspective-at-1-4#comment109922_39098), there should really be acceleration and deceleration, meaning that this is only an approximation unless we know $v(\tau)$.

If $$\frac{dv}{d\tau}\neq0$$then things get more complicated, as [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/109777/56299) shows. The equation for proper time during a period of constant acceleration is
$$\tau=\frac{c}{a}\text{arcosh}\left(\frac{xa}{c^2}+1\right)$$
Therefore, all you have to do is let the ship accelerate for a distance $x_1-x_0$, stay at constant speed for a distance $x_2-x_1$, and decelerate for a distance $x_3-x_2$, where $x_3$ is the distance to Tau Ceti.